# boolean difference

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i am doing a boolean difference operation with a human head and a cube to make a mold for the head. after numerous attempts i can achieve the boolean diffenence however, the head has a mouth cavity and that cavity does not get removed from the cube. i've tried to fill the head to make it solid but there not way to do that. i've tried shrinkwrap too but that doesnt work. is there anyway to just get the exterior of the head [image: boolean different]to be removed from the cube?

i want to print the mold (cubes) not the model, then use that to pour conventional materials such as plaster of paris.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you add more information about what you are trying to do? Perhaps some screenshots of your scene and objects, especially ones that show the topology of your object's mesh and what you are trying to achieve? It's hard to help with so little info, maybe post a link to your blend file if you can using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Boolean operations only work well on manifold, closed, watertight meshes with no wholes, gaps or geometry inconsistencies, and no overlapping, coplanar faces or duplicated geometry. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/7914#7914